# TextBox is not updating its visual when stringformat is defined

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to bind a textbox to a doule on my VM. in XAML I have this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"    Margin="0,0,0,5">
        <Binding Path="Offset" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  Mode="TwoWay" StringFormat="{}{0:F2}}">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox>
```

and on VM I have this:

```
  public double Offset
    {
        get
        {
            return this.offset;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value <= 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Not Valid!");
            }

            this.offset = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Offset);
        }
    }
```

But when I set a value to Offset on vm, nothing is shown on view.

If I remove the string format, I am getting suitable display on View.

```
  <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"    Margin="0,0,0,5">
        <Binding Path="Offset" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  Mode="TwoWay" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox>
```

How can I have both stringformat and also can set offset on VM?

Comment: I think you got an extra `}` in the end, should be `StringFormat="{}{0:F2}"`. And are you sure you are using `this.Offset` in the `Offset` property, or it's a typo?

Comment: @Bolu: you are right. It is fixed now. Thank you. Please put it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: As this question was caused by a simple typographical error and can no longer be replicated, I have voted to close it as 'off topic'. In time, other reviewers will also vote to close it and so it *will* be closed. As it will be of no help to anyone but you, you could save some time and reviewing if you delete it yourself (after you have accepted @Bolu's answer). Many thanks.

Comment: @Sheridan: Ok I will do this after I accepted Bolu answer, In 3 minutes!

Comment: Thanks... it's appreciated.

Comment: @Sheridan, I would argue that as there is a high possibility of reproducing this error by other user, I'm not 100% sure this needs to be deleted..

Comment: @Sheridan: I can not close it! When I tried to close it, it says: Sorry, This question has answers and can not be deleted; Flag it for moderator attention instead. I am gong to flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @Bolu, please don't make such ridiculous suggestions... this website is *not* here for people that make typing mistakes. Don't worry though, you won't lose your reputation... That's why I asked mans to delete it *after* accepting your answer.

Comment: Ok @mans, that's no problem... we can let the reviewers close it when they get around to it.

Comment: @Sheridan, I'm not worried about the reputation, I'm defending my purpose of answering.. *Question to ask yourself: Will the post (and its answer) ever benefit anyone else, or is it so specific to the OP's situation that it will only benefit him?* [REF](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255569/352101)

Comment: @Bolu, to be clear... this is not my decision. These are the rules here on Stack Overflow... perhaps you should read them? In the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page of the Help Center, you'll see a list of things that are considered 'Off Topic' on this website. Point 2 says *Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused a simple typographical error.* So, anyone that follows these rules (most people) and who have the relevant reputation to enable them to review close requests will vote to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an extra `}` in the end, change that to:

`StringFormat="{}{0:F2}"`

(this is probably left over during copy from something like `<TextBox Text="{Binding Offset, StringFormat={}{0:F2}}" />` )